ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'
I have a dataframe that calculates the moving average of covid cases and the rate of variation of cases over the last 7 days. I am encountering an error when trying to group my dataframe by "city" and "date". If you remove groupby, the code runs but the result is wrong
  casos_por_estado['soma_casos_7d'] = casos_por_estado.groupby(['municipio'])['casosnovos'].rolling(window=7).sum()
  casos_por_estado['media_casos_7d'] = casos_por_estado['soma_casos_7d'] / 7
  casos_por_estado['tx_variacaocasos'] = casos_por_estado['media_casos_7d']/casos_por_estado['media_casos_7d'].shift(periods=14)
  casos_por_estado['tendenciacasos'] = casos_por_estado['tx_variacaocasos'].apply(get_trend)

  if temp_is_empty:
    temp_ = casos_por_estado
    temp_is_empty = False
  else:
    temp_ = pd.concat([casos_por_estado], ignore_index=True)
    #temp_ = pd.concat([s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in to_concat], axis=1)


casos_covid = temp_
temp_ = None


read notice: [mre]

If the code runs when removing groupby - maybe some-value in the column 'municipio' being passed to groupby is not string/object?
Maybe you can check using -
print(casos_por_estado['municipio'].apply(type).value_counts())

or
non_string_values = casos_por_estado['municipio'].apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str))
print(casos_por_estado[non_string_values]['municipio'].head())

